# How reverse query OnetoOne Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following relation:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.OnetoOneField('Customer')
    """ Other stuff """

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    """ Other stuff """
```

My question is:

If I do a query, let's say:

`inv_q = Invoice.objects.filter(date=today())`

How can I get all related Customers from this Query?

`cus_q = Customer.objects.filter(id__in=inv_q.customer)`

Do I have to create a customer manager for that?

## Edit 1:

I am generating a `report.json` file that must contain both information. In order not to hit the database and fetch all customers, I want to have information from the customers of the selected invoices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do following:

```
cus_q = Customer.objects.filter(invoice__in=inv_q)
```

or, directly with [field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
cus_q = Customer.objects.filter(invoice__date=today())
```

Comment: I am generating a `report.json` file that must contain both information (invoices and customers). In order not to hit the database and fetch all customers, I want to have information from the customers of the selected invoices.

Comment: In that case, you can use `select_related` as pointed out by @Sayse in the other answer.

Comment: But in this case I won't be able to retrieve all customers at once, will I? It seems I have to loop through each object to get the customer.

Comment: If you want the queryset for the invoices and also the related customers, then you can after you have the invoices you can use the first option in the answer to get the customers.

Comment: That's exactly it! I thought about doing that, but since I thought there was no column called "invoices" I thought it would not work. I misunderstood the concept of these queries on Django. Thanks AKS :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't quite make sense what you are trying to do, you can use a field lookup to filter customers by their invoice date

```
Customer.objects.filter(invoice__date=today())
```

which seems most appropriate

Otherwise you can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) to pre-retrieve the customer model for each invoice, then when accessing via `invoice_instance.customer` there won't be a further query

```
Invoice.objects.filter(date=today()).select_related('customer')
```

Comment: I am generating a `report.json` file that must contain both information (invoices and customers). In order not to hit the database and fetch all customers, I want to have information from the customers of the selected invoices. The query must be made by invoices, from this point, when generating the report the customers must come together.

Comment: @Ev. - I have never used `report.json` so I don't know how that serializes (or works). `select_related` stops a second query though.

Comment: Is it possible to get all customers related to invoice query in one single object/query? I will print information from both invoices and customers to a file, to do some post-processing. That's why I need a dump of the whole customers table (related to the selected invoices, as I mentioned).

Comment: @Ev. - That is something for the serializer to do, aside from `select_related` there isn't a way (I know of) to retrieve values for both models in a single query.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a single query, it can be two. I just need a dump of the whole customer row for each of those invoices. Something like: `Customer.objects.filter(customer__in=Invoices.QUERY)`.